# How to crop a raster image by coordinates in python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, crop, raster

I have a GeoTiff in UTM32 and coordinates of a rectangle also in UTM32.
(This projection may not always be the case, but the projections will always be the same)

I simply need to **crop the image using the rectangle**.

The rectangle is given by: (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

```
699934.584491, 700160.946739, 6168703.00544, 6169364.0093
```

I know how to make a polygon from the points, how to make a shapefile from the polygon, and I know how to create a masked numpy array using the points. However, I don't know how to use the polygon, the shapefile or the mask to actually crop the image.

I already looked at the description at:
https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#clip-a-geotiff-with-shapefile

However, I don't really understand it and it seems overly complicated. (like I don't know what histogram stretching is supposed to be doing there except confusing)

Answer (score 3):

Akin's answer is mostly right, but doesn't provide a complete explanation.

You can crop a gdal file using [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html), which can be used in python via `gdal.Translate`.

##### Best option: projwin

The easiest way is with the [projwin](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-projwin) flag, which takes 4 values:

`window = (upper_left_x, upper_left_y, lower_right_x, lower_right_y)`

These values are in map coordinates. The bounds of the input file can be obtained via `gdalinfo input_raster.tif` from the command line.

*NOTE*: for many coordinate systems, `ymax` is actually less than `ymin`, so it's important to use "upper_left" and "lower_right" to identify the coordinates instead of "max" and "min." Akin's answer didn't work for me because of this difference.

The complete solution, then is:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

upper_left_x = 699934.584491
upper_left_y = 6169364.0093
lower_right_x = 700160.946739
lower_right_y = 6168703.00544
window = (upper_left_x,upper_left_y,lower_right_x,lower_right_y)

gdal.Translate('output_crop_raster.tif', 'input_raster.tif', projWin = window)
```

##### Additional option: srcwin

[srcwin](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-srcwin) is another gdal_translate flag similar to `projwin`, but takes in the pixel and line window via an offset and size, instead of using the map coordinate bounds. You would use it like this:

```py
window = (offset_x, offset_y, size_x, size_y)
gdal.Translate('output_crop_raster.tif', 'input_raster.tif', srcWin = window)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use bbox = (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)

```
from osgeo import gdal

bbox = (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)

gdal.Translate('output_crop_raster.tif', 'input_raster.tif', projWin = bbox)
```

Comment: This answer is based on the `projwin` argument for `gdal_translate` [documented here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-projwin).  `xmin` and `ymin` are actually `upper_left_x` and `upper_left_y` coordinates, while `xmax` and `ymax` should be named `lower_right_x` and `lower_right_y`. You can see these coordinates for the input file using `gdalinfo input_raster.tif`.