# crop tiff file with Python

Tags: python

Good day to everyone
I have a problem: coordinates are taken as input (like en example below) I have a tiff file. it is necessary to cut the tiff file at the given coordinates. I've been looking for a few days and haven't found a suitable solution. Can anyone help me solve the problem or suggest a way. thank you all in advance.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              26.323586194745644,
              51.5136424962856
            ],
            [
              26.318436259612497,
              51.51043743329282
            ],
            [
              26.32558894729766,
              51.50830059935572
            ],
            [
              26.333599957503935,
              51.51168387347343
            ],
            [
              26.323586194745644,
              51.5136424962856
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

One of the examples that i found:

```
import os
from itertools import product
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows

in_path = 'images'
input_filename = 'B12.tiff'

out_path = 'result/B12'
output_filename = 'tile_{}-{}.tif'


def get_tiles(ds, width=256, height=256):
    nols, nrows = ds.meta['width'], ds.meta['height']
    offsets = product(range(0, nols, width), range(0, nrows, height))
    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=nols, height=nrows)
    for col_off, row_off in offsets:
        window = windows.Window(col_off=col_off, row_off=row_off, width=width, height=height).intersection(big_window)
        transform = windows.transform(window, ds.transform)
        yield window, transform


with rio.open(os.path.join(in_path, input_filename)) as inds:
    tile_width, tile_height = 256, 256

    meta = inds.meta.copy()

    for window, transform in get_tiles(inds):
        print(window)
        meta['transform'] = transform
        meta['width'], meta['height'] = window.width, window.height
        outpath = os.path.join(out_path,output_filename.format(int(window.col_off), int(window.row_off)))
        with rio.open(outpath, 'w', **meta) as outds:
            outds.write(inds.read(window=window))
```

Comment: you can use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html). it manages .tiff and use `Image.resize`

Comment: I think I see a couple of issues here. Firstly, there seem to be 5 coordinate pairs, which doesn't make a rectangle which you can crop to - it makes a polygon. So, I guess you'd need to draw the filled polygon on an alpha/transparency layer and use that to mask in (make visible) the points inside and mask out (make transparent) those outside. Secondly, I guess your coordinates are latitudes/longitudes, whereas PIL uses (x,y) pixel coordinates so you'll probably need something like `gdal` to translate.

Comment: Alternatively, if there are really 5 polygon vertices, you could just use the max and min latitude of those 5 as the top and bottom, then the max and min longitude of the 5 as right and left to crop. Then you'd actually get the minimum rectangle that encloses your shape, i.e. you'd get the polygon and some small amount of extra unnecessary extra stuff around the edges.

Comment: @NicoCaldo in my case pillow can not op[en raster(satellite) image. is any other ways?

Comment: You can open TIFFs with `tifffile` https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/

Comment: @MarkSetchell opening file is not so difficult. My problem is Finding a polygon in tif file and crop it. Can you give the source where i can find the example of using of gdal? I foun one way but can not solve the problem.  this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242716/how-to-crop-a-raster-image-by-coordinates-in-python

Comment: Use 51.5136 as the top, 51.5083 as the bottom, 26.3184 as left and 26.3336 as right.

Comment: This problem solved. You can see solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446382/crop-tiff-file-with-python